# Splitting arraylist into seperate arrays with individual elements from imported data

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, import, split

Example, this is being inputted into the program:

(a)

(!a;c)

(b;!c)

I need to use !a alone without ;c attached to it for example.

My idea was for all to be stored in an arraylist, and then each set of brackets would be split into different arrays with individual elements. i.e it would become [[a], [!a, c], [b, !c]].

What was said above is the idea that i had in mind. This is the code that i have written which doesn't work well. I hope what i am trying to say is understood and i'd appreciate the help

```
Scanner scanClauses = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));

 System.out.println("\nSuccessfully read file!\n");

 ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> clauses = new ArrayList<>();
 ArrayList<String> query = new ArrayList<>();

 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 scan.useDelimiter("\n");

 //To take KB and put it in an array
 while (scanClauses.hasNextLine()) {
       clauses.add(new ArrayList<>());
       for (ArrayList<String> c : clauses) {
           c.add(scanClauses.next());
           System.out.println(c);
       }
 }
```

Comment: The three inputs are three lines in your file and in one line you use semicomma to separate elements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding an empty `ArrayList` to `clauses` in the following line of your code:

```
clauses.add(new ArrayList<>());
```

Do it as follows:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
        List<ArrayList<String>> clauses = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> query;
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            // Remove '(' and ')' from the line and then split it on ';' to get an array
            // of tokens. Then, convert the array to a new `ArrayList`. 
            query = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(scan.nextLine().replace("(", "").replace(")", "").split(";")));
            clauses.add(query);
        }
        System.out.println(clauses);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[[a], [!a, c], [b, !c]]
```

**Content of file.txt:**

```
(a)
(!a;c)
(b;!c)
```

Comment: I believe the output meets your requirement - isn't it? Feel free to let me know if there are additional requirements or better you post a new question with the additional requirement(s).

Comment: Yes, that's what i was looking for. Sorry as i saw the answer before the edit. 

Regarding if i where to access for example [!a, c] how should that be done?

Comment: You are most welcome. *If I were to access for example [!a, c] how should that be done?* - `System.out.println(clauses.get(1));` will print `[!a, c]`. Feel free to comment should there be any further doubt/issue.